# How to markup an article update date?

Tags: html, semantic-markup

I was reading on `<article>` and it seems that when you should use `pubdate` to mark up the *published date* of the article.

That's fine and all if you have published the article once and it was the permanent version of the thing.

However, what happens if you update the article? Is there a way to markup when it was updated? Should I use `pubdate` for updates too?

I'm not sure that's the case since it would mean machines won't be able to distinguish between when an article was created and when it was updated.

How do you markup the date an article was updated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**pubdate was removed from the HTML5-specs about 3 years ago.**

Thus there are no rules or best practices for it... Just read about the < time > element instead:

http://html5doctor.com/time-and-data-element/

http://www.brucelawson.co.uk/2012/best-of-time/